# Grids not working in Intel XDK

Tags: android, ios, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, intel-xdk

I've created a demo app with XDK.
I am using grids to center the controls on the page.
When I am running in XDK emulator, the controls appear fine, and same for the GenyMotion VM running droid.

But When I am installing the application on a real android phone, the alignments are completely destroyed.

I am having a real hard time figuring out what is going wrong!!

I am attaching screenshots to depict the scenario :

1) On the designer :
[image: The Designer]

2) On XDK Emulator :
[image: The app on XDK Emulator]

3) On Micromax CanvasHD :
[image: The same app on CasvasHD]

Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="xhr.js"></script>
    <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/init-app.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_user_scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="marginal/marginal-position.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="xdk/appdesigner/js/rest-of-space.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="row-alignment-1">

    <div class="upage" id="mainpage" data-role="page">

      <div class="upage-outer">
        <div class="uib-header header-bg container-group inner-element uib_w_1" data-uib="layout/header" data-ver="0">
          <h2></h2>
          <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
          <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"></div>
          <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="upage-content ac0 content-area vertical-col" id="page_22_9">

          <div class="uib-grid widget uib_w_3 grid-text grid-height d-margins" data-uib="layout/grid" data-ver="0">
            <div class="uib-grid-row">
              <div class="uib-grid-cell widget-container"></div>
              <div class="uib-grid-cell widget-container"></div>
              <div class="uib-grid-cell widget-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="uib-grid-row">
              <div class="uib-grid-cell widget-container"></div>
              <div class="uib-grid-cell widget-container">
                <button class="btn widget uib_w_4 d-margins btn-default" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" id="btnVerify">Check</button>
              </div>
              <div class="uib-grid-cell widget-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="uib-grid-row">
              <div class="uib-grid-cell widget-container"></div>
              <div class="uib-grid-cell widget-container"></div>
              <div class="uib-grid-cell widget-container"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uib-footer uib-footer-fixed footer-bg container-group inner-element uib_w_2" data-uib="layout/footer" data-ver="0">
          <h2></h2>
          <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
          <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"></div>
          <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I am not sure whats the cause of this problem.

Looking forward to some assistance on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Android device do u have ?

The grid uses flex-box, which may not be supported on older Android webviews, try building `Crosswalk for Android` build in Intel XDK.

`Crosswalk for Android` packages app with a newer Chromium based web runtime, which has more html5 capability than thats in the default webview on Android devices. Here is more details about Crosswalk build versus regular Android build: https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/why-use-crosswalk-for-android-builds

Comment: I did and in Cross-walk AJAX fails again. It was working in the regular build after fixing the domain list to my domain or just *.

Comment: Crosswalk version 10 works, version 11 and 12 fails!

Comment: what fails on 11 and 12? ajax or grid UI?

Comment: The ajax fails in 11 and 12 cross-walk builds and works in 7.

Comment: what is the cli version set to?

Comment: cli version is n/a for cross-walk. Its present in the android tab and its set to   3.5